# Using Voting Classifier, accuracy still too low

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am using a small dataset, and using the following code. The accuracy is near 30% even using the voting classifier with Grid Search. Here is the link to dataset. 
Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rVdhrhrXZtGvAyUrGuUheRRpMtLQJxSu

I need the accuracy to be around 60% at least. Don't know, totally stucked. I have to use Voting classifier with best weight. I have all the code, but don't know where I am missing.

Can you please suggest me, what extra processing steps, I can do. or is there is something wrong with my code.

```
# Imports
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 12
def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()


import seaborn as sns
from time import time
from operator import itemgetter
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Machine learning
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifierCV
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


df = pd.read_csv("Employees.csv")


from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df.company = le.fit_transform(df.company)
df.age = le.fit_transform(df.age)
df.sex = le.fit_transform(df.sex)
df.qualification = le.fit_transform(df.qualification)
df.experience = le.fit_transform(df.experience)
df.customers = le.fit_transform(df.customers)
df.interesting = le.fit_transform(df.interesting)
df.sources = le.fit_transform(df.sources)
df.usage = le.fit_transform(df.usage)
df.devices = le.fit_transform(df.devices)

print('Splitting data into training and testing')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.iloc[:, 0:15], df.iloc[:, 15], test_size=0.3, random_state=10)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score

X = np.array(df.iloc[:, 0:15])
y = np.array(df.iloc[:, 15]).astype(int)

clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf2 = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', C = 1000, gamma = 0.001, probability=True)
clf3 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf4 = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, n_estimators=300, bootstrap = False, min_samples_leaf = 7,
                                       min_samples_split = 7, max_features = 10, max_depth = None, criterion = 'gini')
clf5 = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=1, n_estimators=100, learning_rate = 0.1,
                                min_samples_leaf = 20, min_samples_split = 3, max_features = 6, max_depth = 16)
clf6 = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100, algorithm='SAMME', base_estimator = RidgeClassifierCV(), learning_rate = 0.5)
clf7 = BaggingClassifier(n_estimators=100, base_estimator = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5), max_features = 6)

clf_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4', 'w5', 'w7', 'mean', 'std'])

i = 0
for w1 in range(1,4):
    for w2 in range(1,4):
        for w3 in range(1,4):
            for w4 in range(1,4):
                for w5 in range(1,4):
                    for w7 in range(1,4):
                        if len(set((w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w7))) == 1: # skip if all weights are equal
                            continue
                        eclf = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr', clf1), ('svc', clf2), ('knn', clf3), ('rf', clf4), 
                                                            ('gb', clf5), ('bagg', clf7)], 
                                                voting='soft', weights=[w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w7])
                        scores = cross_val_score(estimator=eclf, 
                                                 X=X,
                                                 y=y,
                                                 cv=3,
                                                 scoring='accuracy',
                                                  n_jobs=1)

                        clf_df.loc[i] = [w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w7, scores.mean(), scores.std()]
                        i += 1

clf_df



    w1  w2  w3  w4  w5  w7  mean    std
0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 0.320952    0.061594
1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 0.304339    0.048603
2   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 0.298244    0.064792
3   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 0.298244    0.064792
4   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 0.288272    0.050571
5   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 0.307880    0.052788
6   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 2.0 0.287831    0.037529
7   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 3.0 0.309547    0.044869
8   1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 0.312202    0.050178
9   1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 0.318735    0.083757
10  1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 3.0 0.313089    0.045554
11  1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 0.323947    0.044287
12  1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 0.305666    0.050826
13  1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 0.339127    0.048330
14  1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 0.288714    0.063720
15  1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 2.0 0.312644    0.063469
16  1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 0.311316    0.058367
17  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 1.0 0.330479    0.077330
18  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 0.340896    0.064767
19  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 3.0 0.311316    0.058367
20  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 0.305225    0.037695
21  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 0.338685    0.036169
22  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 0.340454    0.051494
23  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 0.318297    0.038370
24  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 0.300458    0.056722
25  1.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 0.319180    0.064249
26  1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.230885    0.021098
27  1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 0.209067    0.038850
28  1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 0.242626    0.048283
29  1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 0.283509    0.036564
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
696 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 0.313089    0.045554
697 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 0.320949    0.086164
698 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 0.327485    0.089039
699 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 0.320507    0.073512
700 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.249162    0.048175
701 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 0.255600    0.033159
702 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 0.244844    0.037530
703 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 0.293926    0.023029
704 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 0.271768    0.018016
705 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 0.283509    0.036564
706 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 0.271323    0.028955
707 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 3.0 2.0 0.267001    0.034206
708 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 3.0 3.0 0.289603    0.028225
709 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 0.255257    0.037280
710 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 0.243513    0.041866
711 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 3.0 0.276192    0.068067
712 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 0.318297    0.038370
713 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 0.271765    0.042210
714 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 0.269106    0.073391
715 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 1.0 0.318738    0.051217
716 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 2.0 0.288272    0.050571
717 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 0.311320    0.023631
718 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 1.0 0.226563    0.028543
719 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 2.0 0.277418    0.019540
720 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 3.0 0.224791    0.034766
721 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 0.275204    0.021578
722 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 0.285278    0.058999
723 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 0.271765    0.042210
724 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 0.273534    0.063532
725 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 0.294363    0.071240
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you do not have good enough data to achieve such accuracy?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, I believe the same. you are correct. I have to increase it, Is there not any option, I can enhance accuracy on that same dataset.

Comment: @AmarKumar: that depends on the data, which is exactly juanpa's point.  It may *not* be theoretically possible with the given data, in which case there is nothing you can do about it.  Determining that possibility will take applying some information theory.

Comment: Throwing the kitchen sink at a problem wont get you the desired accuracy rate. What is your null-rate?  Maybe some improvement on that should be first target.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your dataset and approach:

**1. You have few observations and many classes**. If you call `y_train.value_counts()`, you'll see

```
16    22
18    17
15    17
17    13
12    11
13     8
19     7
10     7
14     6
11     6
8      5
9      1
4      1
```

It means that the most frequent class has only 22 observations, and the infrequent classes have only one observation in them. Overall, you have 13 classes per 121 observations, which is too few. Upsampling techniques do not help, because they do not increase available information, but just reweight it.

A few possible recommendations would be:

- to get more data - at least few tens observations per each class
- to merge 13 classes into 2 or 3 more general groups
- if the classes are ordered, to use this ordering information (e.g. there is an ordered logit model in `statsmodels`)
- if your model will be used to prescribe some action to the employees, try predicting results of this action directly, as a numeric variable. I mean, apply regression instead of classification, if your final goal is to predict or influence some numeric outcome.

**2. You encode categorical variables with arbitrary numbers**. This is an artifact of using `LabelEncoder`. E.g. you encode `company4` as 3, `company3` as 2, `company2` as 1, `company1` as 0. As a result, all your classifiers "think" that e.g. `company2` is in some sense between `company1` and `company3`, which may be not the case in any sense. Moreover, you encode ages `['10 To 14 Years', '15 To 20 Years', '5 To 9 Years', 'Less Than 5 Years', 'More Than 20 Years']` as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, which completely ignores real differences in the ages.

What you can do about it:

- Use one-hot encoding with your unordered categorical variables
- Encode the oredered categorical variables (age, qualification, experience, and usage) with labels that have meaningful order, e.g. Unfortunately, you have to do it manyally.
- try more advanced techniques of categorical variables encoding, e.g. with mean value of the target variable.

**3. You use unscaled features with distance-based algorithms**. `SVC` and `KNeighborsClassifier` use Euclidean distance between observations for training and prediction. But Euclidean distance really reflects (dis)similarity only if features have scale corresponding to their importance. In your data, `sex` has values in {1,2}, and `exf1` in [4-20]. In terms of distance, it means that `exf1` is 16 times more important than `sex`.

For LogisticRegression, arguably the most robust classifier of your 7, feature scaling is also important, because it regularizes (shrinks) its coefficients according to their size.

If all features are expected to be equally important, they need to have equal scale, which is achieved e.g. with `StandardScaler` from `sklearn`.

**To sum up, instead of choosing the best algorithm, concentrate on your data, its preprocessing, and the task you want to accomplish.**